# Camel Using aggregation and completing on dynamic completion size

Tags: java, apache-camel

Hi I have a camel route that splits an incoming message, i then want to aggregate this message, but i dont know how many messages will be split.

i have used the following:

```
.aggregate(new AggregateStrategy()).header("uuid").completionSize(header("CamelSplitSize"))
```

this doesnt work, and it hangs... however if i set the completion size toa numerical value it works.

Anyone any ideas how to dynamically aggregate, and wait for completion. by the way the header is set before the split.

Comment: what do you meant by dynamically? where do cou want to change this?

Comment: I mean that i have a message that is split into X number of messages,  i dont know how many messages will result from the split. but i need to aggregate those messages at the end before i pass the list on.

It would be good if i could tell the aggregator to complete when all split messages have arrived.

Comment: that is not how aggregators work. You dont have to tell the split size. The method `public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange)` takes two arguments.

Comment: but is there a way i can wait for it to complete, ie all messages have arrived.

Comment: if aou have to wait for all the messages to arrive and then do something, then what is the use of splitting

Comment: No i have split the message  X-> a,b,c,d... i want to wait for a,b,c,d to arrive and create a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do **not need an aggregator nor a completion size** for this. You simply need a [**Splitter EIP with an aggregation strategy**](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.15.x/eips/split-eip.html#_split_and_aggregate_example).

In the linked example you can see that such a Splitter does a **re-aggregation of whatever it has splitted before**. No matter how much parts were resulting from the split.

```
// a Splitter with an AggregationStrategy
.split([yourSplitCriteria], new MyAggregationStrategy())
    // each splitted message part is sent to this bean 
    .to("bean:PartProcessor")
    // you can do whatever you want in here
    // end the split to re-aggregate the message parts
.end()
// here, after the split-ending you get the re-aggregated messages
```

Comment: okay so is it possible that i have a message X which is split into a,b,c,d sent to another queue to process and after that can I group a,b,c,d up, i dont care about X after i have split it?

Comment: Basically, yes. **But** to use this Pattern your processed parts need to reach the `end()` of the Splitter. That means that all calls inside the Splitter must be request/reply. If you make a call inside the Splitter that is one-way (standard for sending to a queue), this call just "leaves" the Splitter, its result is not returned and can therefore not be included in the aggregation.

Comment: Just actual link on example https://camel.apache.org/components/3.15.x/eips/split-eip.html#_split_and_aggregate_example

Comment: I fixed the link in the answer too, thanks